# What might be the "Blue Storm Republic" mentioned by a Chinese history of Europe?

Tags: europe

Today, when I read a book about the history of Europe ,when it comes to the European Union, it described as the following words "Main governing bodies of EU include:The Council of the European Union,...,Blue Storm Republic".

What's the "Blue Storm Republic"?

Comment: Do you have specific citation? Book author/name/ISBN/page?

Comment: [Sujarkama](http://meta.history.stackexchange.com/q/618/1401). Please include your references.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is most likely a bad translation from Chinese (or more specifically, **bad translation from English to Chinese, then literally translated back into English**).

Original text was 蓝色风暴共和国： - literally translated as "Blue storm Republic".

If you google `"Blue Storm Republic"` or `"The Council of the European Union" "blue storm"` most of the links are Chinese (the main one to some encyclopedia translated from Chinese). Here's [one example](http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=zh-CN&u=http://www.standard123.com/article/Europa/std10826203423.html&ei=qOD9TpFG497RAeb39LkC&sa=X&oi=translate&ct=result&resnum=7&ved=0CFQQ7gEwBg&prev=/search?q=%2522The%2bCouncil%2bof%2bthe%2bEuropean%2bUnion%2522%2b%2522blue%2bstorm%2522&hl=en&biw=1280&bih=963&prmd=imvns). Here's [another](http://en.zhaopei.com/html/0224/14958.html).

Based on the list of institutions in the article and their order, the bulk of data seems to be likely lifted from the [Institutions of the European Union Wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Institutions_of_the_European_Union).

The agencies in the Wiki article NOT listed in the Chinese page are:

- European Environment Agency
- Europol
- Publications Office
- The European Personnel Selection Office (EPSO)
- European Administrative School
- European Ombudsman
- European Data Protection Supervisor

It's hard to tell which of these became mis-translated as 蓝色风暴共和国, but I'm going to venture a guess that it's Europol (European Police Office).

---

The only **Blue Storm** associated with EU is an [IBM super-computer](http://betanews.com/2001/12/21/ibm-unleashes-blue-storm-in-europe/) bought in 2001 for The European Centre for Medium-Range Weather Forecasts (ECMWF).

Comment: Thank you,I read this from a Chinese bilingual book,called"A Very short history of europe",I don't know Europe very well,so  I choose this book to gain some knowledge about the Europe.

Comment: Frankly speaking ,I googled and checked the Wikipedia ,but I don't analyse this question as you did.I really appreciate your answer,It's good.Thanks!

Comment: LOL, this is hilarious. A Lady Mondegreen moment.

Comment: Also, if Europol is what's meant, be aware that it isn't among the "main governing bodies of the EU". It doesn't actually tell anybody what to do, and although it provides a forum for the various national police forces to co-operate it doesn't do any EU-wide policing either!